# for...in looping working in Chrome, but not in IE?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, for-loop, for-in-loop

Ok peep's here's the problem...

---

This is a **simplified** version of a file I'm writing...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>_</title>
        <script src="/sifu/query/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            /********************************************************/
            str='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
            /********************************************************/
            function pop(){
                /****************************/
                sx='for(ia in str)'+'\n';
                for(ia in str)
                    sx+='\n'+ia+'   => '+str[ia];
                enX.innerText=sx;
                /****************************/
                sy='for(ib=0;ib<str.length;ib++)'+'\n';
                for(ib=0;ib<str.length;ib++)
                    sy+='\n'+ib+'   => '+str[ib];
                enY.innerText=sy;
                /****************************/
            }
            /********************************************************/
            $(document).ready(function(){
                pop()
            })
            /********************************************************/
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="width:100%;text-align:center">
            <tr>
                <td id="enX">enX</td>
                <td id="enY">enY</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Demo

```js
str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

function pop() {
  sx = 'for(ia in str)' + '\n';
  for (ia in str) {
    sx += '\n' + ia + ' => ' + str[ia];
  }
  enX.innerText = sx;

  sy = 'for(ib=0;ib<str.length;ib++)' + '\n';
  for (ib = 0; ib < str.length; ib++) {
    sy += '\n' + ib + ' => ' + str[ib];
  }
  enY.innerText = sy;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  pop()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;text-align:center">
  <tr>
    <td id="enX">enX</td>
    <td id="enY">enY</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

When I load it in **chrome** it works fine... I get two equal columns of **0-25|a-z**.

---

Yet, when I Load it in **IE**,

> Column **X**, only has the header `for(ia in str)` and contains no instances of the loop ie: `0 => a` etc...

And

> Column **Y**, contains both the header `for(ib=0;ib<str.length;ib++)` and **26** instances of `# => undefined`, where `#` is the loop number.

---

---

I'm sorry to ask such a *simplistic* question peep's but I've recently been teaching myself how to code a web page specifically for **chrome**, leaving **IE** behind, and it seems that in the time it's taken to learn how to code in **chrome** I've forgotten the fundamentals of coding in **IE**...

---

### All pointers welcome... just explain where I'm going wrong plz

Comment: Hi, what version of IE are you using?

Comment: v11.0.9600.16428
update: RTM(KB2841134)

Comment: thing is ive just run the demo snippet from this page in both chrome and ie and they both work?

Comment: You should [never use `for in` loops on array structures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572), but you should even less do so on strings.

Comment: blah blah blah, how many time do i have to hear this...i'm using **for...in** deal with it, I'm looking for a reason why it won't work, not why i shouldn't use it!

Comment: now if u said something like IE11 doesn't support bracket notation on strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the reference but I am fairly sure that some versions of IE do not support indexing strings, you are supposed to use the the `charAt` function. That being true, in those versions of IE, the `for .. in` has nothing to iterate over for a string.

By converting your string to an array using `.split('')` and using `for .. in` on that the code should work in all browsers.

Comment: makes sense dude, it appears to have nothing to iterate..

Am aware of the `.split()` conversion just didn't know why it was happening.

No doubt i've updated ie since coding in it, but get this..

i've just added the following line of code to the above `d1.innerText=cha:{str[0]`

and lo-an-behold it displays `cha:{undefined}` in IE?  Would this fall under the same indexing rules